# Turning off the drawer header in a specific screen in bottom tab navigation in drawer navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a very big problem I am using two navigations in one app the first one is the drawer navigator this is how I use the drawer navigator:

```js
 <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        },
      }}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomSidebarMenu {...props} />}
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
        activeBackgroundColor: 'red',
        itemStyle: {marginVertical: 20},
      }}>
      <Drawer.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTitle: () => (
            <Image
              style={{height: 150, width: 100, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
              source={require('../assets/images/referans2.png')}
            />
          ), // Title to appear in the header
          headerRight: ({navigation, scene}) => (
            // Custom component to appear on the right side of the header
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Pressable>
                <Ionicons
                  name="notifications-outline"
                  size={30}
                  color={'black'}
                />
              </Pressable>
              <Pressable style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}>
                <Ionicons
                  name="chatbubbles-outline"
                  size={30}
                  color={'black'}
                />
              </Pressable>
            </View>
          ),
        }}
        name="Ana Sayfa"
        component={Main}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        options={{headerShown: true}}
        name="Şiparişlerim"
        component={MyOrders}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Adreslerim" component={AddressesScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Üyelik Bilgilerim" component={AccountInfoScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

[

and this gives me the following output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73o8f.png)

In the main function you see here, the bottomtabnavigator, which I use in the whole app, returns.:

```js
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      <Tab.Screen
        component={HomeStack}
        name="Ana Sayfa"
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
            <Ionicons name="home-outline" size={28} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        component={CategoriesStack}
        name="Kategoriler"
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
            <Ionicons name="grid-outline" size={28} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        component={CartStack}
        name="Sepet"
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
            <Ionicons name="cart-outline" size={28} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        component={DiscoverStack}
        name="Keşfet"
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
            <Ionicons name="compass-outline" size={28} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        component={ProfileStack}
        name="Profilim"
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
            <Ionicons name="person-circle-outline" size={28} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

What I want is this; Turning off the header of the drawer in the profile stack in the bottom tab navigator, but I can't do it

but it still didn't close the header of the drawer navigation. Even if I set the headershown of the drawer to false, the header on all screens closes, I'm just not on the screen I want

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, there are 3 nested navigator.

```
Drawer
|---------> BottomTab
|           |---------> ProfileStack
|...        |...
```

If you want to hide or show only specific screen you can use **navigation.setOptions()**

For example,we have a *Profile* screen in *ProfileStack* and get navigation with screen props or useNavigation()

If you want to hide ProfileStack header in Profile:

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => { 
    navigation.setOptions({ headerShown:false }) 
})
```

If you want to hide BottomTab header in Profile:

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => { 
    navigation.getParent().setOptions({ headerShown:false }) 
})
```

If you want to hide Drawer header in Profile:

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => { 
    navigation.getParent().getParent().setOptions({ headerShown:false }) 
})
```

You can use setOptions with *headerShown:true* when the drawer screenOptions *headerShown:false*

react-navigation [getParent()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#getparent) and [setOptions()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#updating-options-with-setoptions) docs